# PHP remove querystring from url

Tags: php

I am building a website and I have come across something that I do not know how to do.

I have a link on every page that members of my website can click, and when they do it takes them to the same page with a query on the end, and a confirmation link like;

```
/contact?tab=hotlink
```

Now on this page is a hidden form and a confirm button, I was going to use                 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], but the previous url is /contact?tab=hotlink and I need it to be...

```
/contact
```

Is there a way to string replace all of the query, I could do it with sessions, but would rather do it another way as it would mean setting alot of unnessessary sessions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The querystring is in

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

So

```
str_replace( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] )
```

should give you the request without the query string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the php [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to extract the base url from the referer by splitting the string on the `?`:

```
$http_referer_full_url = explode("?", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
$http_referer_base_url = $http_referer_full_url[0];
```

@Rijk's answer doesn't work because `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in the example refers to the script currently executing, not the query string from the referrer page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you wouldn't do a page refresh and a querystring for that - you would link to a `#hashed` url instead, like this:

```
<a href="/contact#tab=hotlink">Hotlink</a>
```

You'd then use a Javascript handler to catch the [hashchange event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) (which doesn't require a page refresh, so it is much faster) and dynamically load/display whatever you need on the 'hotlink' tab.

That way, the server wou't even be involved and your pages will be a lot more responsive.

Comment: And if javascript is disabled?

Comment: If you are very concerned about the tiny fraction of no-js users out there, you will need to jump through some hoops, of course. You could degrade the functionality in plenty of ways - use the body class='no-js' trick with css, or inject the #hashes with Javascript, for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` for this